# Difference between closing terminal and closing shell on child processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, process

Opening a new terminal and typing the command `firefox&` inside, `ps -l` gives :

```
4 R  1000 23132 23104 99  80   0 - 2177945 -    pts/27   00:00:07 firefox
```

If the shell is closed with the command `exit`, the firefox child process becomes an orphan but stays open with PPID 1.

The result of `ps -el|grep firefox` is then :

```
4 S  1000 23132     1 14  80   0 - 2233312 poll_s ?      00:00:21 firefox
```

But if the terminal is closed (instead of closing the shell with `exit`), `firefox` is closed as well.

What is happening there ? Is SIGTERM sent to the terminal, the bash shell and all child processes ?

Is there a command that has the same effect as closing the terminal that can be used in the shell ?

Comment: Every time I see such questions, I started to blame the Linux kernel, the job control system relying on the concept of control terminal and signals are a total mess. When shell exit, the kernel just changes PPID, but the shell itself might want to send some signals to children or processes in its process group indicating "I'm dying, take care!". When the terminal emulator process dies, it might do the same or different things.

Comment: When you close the terminal the processes receive a SIGHUP (which is why there is a `nohup` command...)

Comment: It's not dependent from the terminal emulator, it's not a mess, and it's not Linux-specific; although it does vary by shell.  This is long-standardized behaviour and we already have lots of questions on it for people to read, starting with: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407448/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446250/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84737/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158727/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162749/ , …